# Best way to show a lot of data on ASPX web page (Drop down list,

Tags: asp.net, performance, usability

I am doing simple web application with a little business logic. Now I have Drop down list with about 25 000 product and user can choose it.

The application will be probably  slow for users who has slow internet speed. (in company it`s ok)
Is there any component (in Visual Studio) or what is the best way to server so many product to users?

I also try with ComboBox ajax, but in IE 8 CPU was unable to process.

Comment: Server side pagination should just do... Or maybe you'd prefer an autocomplete box showing up after the user entered 2 or 3 chars... kind of autofiletered autocomplete

Comment: Binding 25,000 items to a combo box seems stupid, 1: Server Resources. 2: Usability.  Do you really expect people to scroll through 25,000 items?

Comment: If possible, it sounds like it would be better if the products could be broken down into groups / sub groups / sub-sub-groups.  I think I would want to scream trying to find a single item in 25k.

Comment: Well I also figured out that this is not the best solution. Autocomplete box is it from telerik? I already sub-group product!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you need to display all 25,000 items at once?  I imagine that this will be a usability issue even if it works flawlessly.  With such a massive list, users already must have some sort of idea of what they are choosing.

How about a simple text box that uses ajax to drop down suggested results (similar to google search)?

*Edit* 
You could also break your items into multiple categories and then have a drop down list of categories.  Once the user chooses a category, a second drop down list can display all items in that category or maybe something to break the category down even more.  Similar to: http://www.kbb.com/whats-my-car-worth/

Comment: On your AJAX point - I use jQuery autocomplete with a JSON service, something like this. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp. Works well.